# How to implement HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" in RelativePanel while creating Universal Windows Platforms 10 Apps?

Tags: windows, uwp

I know how to implement it using Grid and StackPanel, can it done here without that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Sure, just align it left and right with panel! For example:

**Horizontal stretch**

```
<RelativePanel>
    <TextBox RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" />
</RelativePanel>
```

If you want vertical stretch, do the similar thing, just align the top and bottom with panel:

**Vertical stretch**

```
<RelativePanel>
    <TextBox RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" />
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: I was trying to add both these panel's on the same Page, but they will overlap each other, what should be done in that case?

Comment: I tried, giving the above '<RealativePanel>' name and put he other in below of it.

Comment: They probably overlap because they're in the same panel (such as Grid), so they need to be arranged correctly inside that panel.

Comment: With use of gird I did it.

Comment: any idea on how this could be done dynamically? where the content is determined at runtime. any workaround?

Comment: To add to this answer, I found that for a combo box I also needed to have HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", and make sure you don't have a width specified.